# HttpClient PostAsync System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post, httpclient

I am working on a simple console program which consumes a webservice(http).
Will post json strings from a txt file.

Tested the snippet below on my own api which was working fine.

Used postman to post a request to the api and did get back a response.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); //should be instatiated once per application

    do
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Method:");
            string Method = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter URI:");
            string uri = Console.ReadLine();

            if (("POST,PUT").Split(',').Contains(Method.ToUpper()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter FilePath:");

                string FilePath = Console.ReadLine();
                iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format(" {0} | {1}", "File Path : <", FilePath + ">"));

                string str_content = (File.OpenText(@FilePath)).ReadToEnd();
                iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format(" {0} | {1}", "String data : <", str_content + ">"));

                //StringContent class creates a formatted text appropriate for the http server/client communication
                StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(str_content, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("1")); //trace

                try
                {
                    //Some risky client call that will call parallell code / async /TPL or in some way cause an AggregateException 
                    var postTask = client.PostAsync(uri, httpContent);
                    iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("2")); //trace

                    postTask.Wait();
                    iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("3")); //trace

                    //gets the response back from the API service
                    HttpResponseMessage result = postTask.Result;
                    iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("4")); //trace

                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("5")); //trace

                        //use this if you want a raw json string
                        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("6")); //trace

                        readTask.Wait();
                        iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("7")); //trace

                        var str_Response = readTask.Result.ToString();
                        iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("8")); //trace
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("WebService Response : \n<" + str_Response + ">");
                        iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format(" {0} | {1}", "WebService Response : <", str_Response + ">"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Status Code = " + result.StatusCode);
                        iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format(" {0} | {1}", "StatusCode", result.StatusCode));
                        iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("9")); //trace
                    }

                }
                catch (AggregateException err)
                {
                    foreach (var errInner in err.InnerExceptions)
                    {
                        iLog.Log(iLog.ERROR, string.Format(errInner.ToString())); //trace                                
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("{0} | {1}", "Exception", ex.Message.ToString()));
            iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("10")); //trace
        }
        iLog.Log(iLog.EVENT, string.Format("{0} {1}", "END", "----------------------------" + "\n"));
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");
    } while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");

}
```

Got back Err:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: With Postman are you using POST or PUT?

Comment: was using a post

Comment: I don't know this comment is rude or not. But please take a look at the naming convention for c#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions
That show how you respect the viewer

Comment: noted will fix, still quite new.

Comment: You can actually also change the signature of the Main method to be `public static async Task Main(string[] args)` to be able to leverage async/await instead of .Wait/.Result

Comment: You can use Postman to generate you working C# code to call your service, see [the documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/)

Comment: Sure, will try it now.

Comment: The code seems fine. What is the http protocol of server? Http or Https?

Comment: the protocol of the server is Http. Btw thanks for the tips, will get the naming convention right the next time. :)

Comment: Hi was able to get it to work by using Caius Jard suggestion of using the adding restsharp nuget and replacing with the Postman generated code.
Still curious why the above code does not work though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi was able to get it to work by using Caius Jard suggestion of using the adding restsharp nuget and replacing with the Postman generated code.